# npm v5 config link does not link

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to get global links working by default with npm v5. The same setup works on npm v4.

Consider the following:

```
npm config set global true
npm config set link true
```

The desired outcome should be that all packages installed by `npm install` are installed globally and all directories in `node_modules` are links to that global install.

In npm v4 this happens as expected. In npm v5 it does not. In npm v5, no packages are installed globally and the dependent packages are copied directly into node_modules as if the configs are being ignored entirely.

Can someone please explain this behavior and how to resolve if possible?